# How to fix the indentation of a question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)
>   [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: “Edits must be at least 6 characters”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must)

Sometimes I'd like to fix the indentation of a code sample in a question, but on submitting I get this error message:

> Edits must be at least 6 non-space characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Is there a way to work around this restriction without altering the content of the question?

Comment: No, seems to work.  Sorry.

Comment: @UphillLuge Might be a suggested edit limitation.  I've seen that message before too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: "Edits must be at least 6 characters"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82534/change-this-behavior-to-allow-for-spelling-corrections-and-the-like-edits-must), [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) and many more.

Answer (score 2):

I edit a **lot** of questions, and I nearly always find more than one issue to fix.  If you can't find anything, I suggest you look harder. I can't find any edits of fewer than six characters in my last 100 edits.

The six-character limitation for suggested edits may be an issue in theory, but I'll bet it's nearly never one in practice. Post an example or two, though, and prove me wrong.

Comment: I routinely correct 1-character typos in titles.

Comment: @Keith, the most recent one-character edit I found from you is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024392/awk-replace-a-column-with-its-hash-value). You could have removed two lines of salutation. I would also have reworded the first sentence, removing the "I wonder how I can". In fact... just made that edit: 31 characters changed.