# Do not enforce 6-non-space-characters suggested edit rule for changes to code formatting

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags)
>   [How to fix the indentation of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111178/how-to-fix-the-indentation-of-a-question)

Why does the rule of "minimum of 6-non-space-characters" for suggested edits apply if you edit the formatting of a post's code?

Sometimes you want to add some spaces for better formatting, or only space line in situation like this:
public int funcName(){

```
    int i=0;
    return i;
}
```

But this is impossible. My suggestion is to not check this rule if changes were only made to the post's code.

Comment: Related: [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters) - Also, come on, there are always other edits you could do that would improve the post far more than code formatting...

Comment: "My offer is not to check this rule if changes was only in code snippet" ... That's not as _simple_ as it sounds, hence the _blanket_ 6 NWS char rule.

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: Suggested edits can only be made when there are 6 or more non-whitespace characters changed, making it impossible for users without the privilege to indent code.

Comment: @minitech Yeap, I know, check my answer...

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox: Sorry, I was typing that particular comment for a long time :)