# Why can I not save an edit for a question when I only edit a code block?

Tags: support, questions, edits, suggested-edits

When I try to edit a question with poor formatting, I received this message:

> **Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:**
>
> - **Nothing appears to have changed**

Here is an example of the edit I tried making:

The OP writes, "Here is an example of the code" followed by:

```
http://jsfiddle.net
```

I tried updating to:

http://jsfiddle.net

See that? I removed the code block. Is there a better way to make these edits?

Comment: Changes need to have 6 non white space edits

Comment: @simchona, that was the error it gave when I tried just adding a semi-colon.  But why should I have to fake 6 char changes to improve the readability of the question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do not enforce 6-non-space-characters suggested edit rule for changes to code formatting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119074/do-not-enforce-6-non-space-characters-suggested-edit-rule-for-changes-to-code-fo), [We're discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on SE sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77233/were-discouraged-from-fixing-typos-and-misspellings-on-se-sites), [Allow under 6 character changes if they are inside code tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76891/allow-under-6-character-changes-if-they-are-inside-code-tags)

Comment: @shana because just taking out the code block is insubstantial

Comment: @Cody Gray, I would agree in spirit except the error message I received is not covered by that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a better way to make these edits?

Yes, make more substantive changes to the body of the post. Fix other things that are wrong, like spelling or grammatical errors, other formatting problems, adding additional tags, improving the title, etc.

This is standard practice when you don't have full edit privileges (and thus must have your edits approved by 2 other users who do have such privileges). Minor or trivial edits are discouraged when suggesting edits, and even if you got the system to recognize that you did, in fact, change something, you'd bump up against the requirement that you must make a *substantial* edit (defined as changing more than 6 non-whitespace characters) in order to submit your suggestion.

The idea is that since you're taking up time of at least two other users to validate your suggestion, and there's hardly ever a post that is otherwise *perfect*, you might as well make all of the other changes at the same time.

Comment: dang man, I was just trying to help.

Comment: I don't know what that comment means or how to interpret it... Helping is encouraged.