# How can I edit questions to add indentation

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to overcome “Edits must be at least 6 characters”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters)
>   [How to fix the indentation of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111178/how-to-fix-the-indentation-of-a-question)

To edit a question, it says that I must enter at least 6 non-space characters.
Maybe there is a question that only needs to add the indentation, thus some space characters (also 4 spaces for short questions).
But it doesn't allow to edit the post if I add only spaces.
What shall I do, avoid to edit the question, or add some extra characters?

Comment: If it's only indentation that's missing then leave it for someone with more than 2k reputation to edit. However, there's likely to be something else wrong with the question too - so fix **everything**.

Comment: As you seem to care about editing: please read about [the difference between line breaks and paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @ChrisF in the comment, we can look out for more improvements in addition to the indentation But Always respecting the original author..

Still, in case we are not finding much to add to the original post, then we may leave the post unaltered rather than adding extra characters just to bypass the 6 char limit..