# What about lowering the edit character limit for characters in code snippets?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, character-limit

[Here is an edit I made today](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3765528/revisions), to correct a misspelled library enum in an answer. Since the edit was only one character, I also had to add a superfluous sentence to get over the character limit required to edit a post.

I've hit this problem before in other edits, always in code snippets. Since the edit limit exists to prevent trivial edits, and since there are many cases where one character code edits are not trivial (`=` to `==` etc), would it make sense to have a lower edit minimum inside code snippets?

Comment: By changing = to ==, you could be answering "what is wrong with this code?"

Comment: I meant in edits to an answer - where it's clear from the words of the answer that they've  mistyped something in the supplied code.

Comment: Just nitpicking, don't mind me.

Comment: I agree that it's a bad idea to edit a question to fix obvious typos ;)

Comment: Users with full edit privileges don't have this limitation. You have to realize that as a user with less than 2,000 reputation, you're getting 2 reputation for your edit. Is removing a letter from a post really worthy of 2 reputation? - [Related Question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115203/141525)

Comment: voted up )
I am not so frequent at SO to gain 2000 rep. quickly ))

Comment: @animuson: No, so the solution is "Small edits don't get reputation".  Not "Small edits are completely banned."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get [full editing rights](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) you can perform smallish edits. Till then, we strongly want to discourage one letter edits. In general if a letter needs some moving around (even in code), there is *almost always* something else that needs fixing.

Like a lower case `instead` that is starting a sentence (for instance).

In this case, I believe this rule ensures edits are substantive products and saves our suggested edit queue from a slew of tiny micro-edits that do not go far enough.

There may be an exception where all that is `neded` is a one letter fix. However, it is a *very rare* edge case, not a general rule.

Comment: You should certainly *encourage* more substantial edits, but not *require* them.  Completely banning people from fixing answers because the fix happens to be small is insane.

Comment: > "fixed a critical error in code. Also, reworded the title to meet the 6-character limit"

Comment: This answer doesn't say what to do if it's the exceptional case.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog Add an extraneous `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to explain the error in a comment. It could be effected in the next edit along with other corrections.

Comment: I disagree. The answer/question will still popup in the list of new posts, but it is more communication involved.