# what's the "official" way to do a one-character edit when there is one character to be added?

Tags: discussion, edits

Do you know what's the difference between text (prose) and code? Yep, you're right: characters **do** matter.

Suppose I was looking for some right command. Suppose I found it and suppose it turned out that there was exactly **one** character missing ( think e.g. `diff -ur` vs `diff -u` ).

And as currently *any* edit is demanded to change at least 6 characters, then my question would be -- *why on Earth I should leave this example incorrect?* ( I mean, I can -- but *why I can't fix it?* ) And if there is an "official" way to edit this -- *then how do I do that*, for Knuth's sake?

I mean, I of course can add and remove some fake characters. But this can then obviously be done as well to bypass *any* protection against minor changes, right? So what's the point in having this ritual then ?

PS. [Let me link here a related (though different) question of mine.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124174/is-it-necessary-to-completely-re-edit-an-old-question-according-to-the-new-guide)

**upd.** [A good proposal, I vote for it )](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116436/what-about-lowering-the-edit-character-limit-for-characters-in-code-snippets)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What about lowering the edit character limit for characters in code snippets?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116436/what-about-lowering-the-edit-character-limit-for-characters-in-code-snippets)

Comment: I mixed up answer and question, but my point stands in either case. If you see an incorrect answer, you want to notify the author of the error. Otherwise, they will never learn what they did wrong and more importantly, they may have meant something entirely different. See e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104438/answer-edits-that-completely-change-the-answer

Comment: @Pekka: So I should leave a comment for the author and hope that he is still active on SO to fix the answer, is that right? I think this is a way to go, though not the best one: first, no one actually reads the comments: I bet you didn't read [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132569/whats-the-official-way-to-do-a-one-character-edit-when-there-is-one-character#comment367037_132570) before posting your question about the "use case"; second, the edits for users with <2000 rep. are reviewed, so we'll still have some independent consideration. Thank you for the discussion.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The "official" way is to fix other problems with the post at the same time.

Alternatively, you can earn at least 2,000 reputation, which will give you the privilege to [edit questions and answers freely](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit), without requiring peer approval. Then you can make as trivial edits as you desire.

Comment: The "edit anywhere" privilege description still states that trivial edits are discouraged.

Comment: accepted as "earn at least 2000 reputation".

Comment: @agf I understand that they are; but it looks reasonable for text, code comments, etc -- no for stuff where chars do matter.

Comment: @ジョージ I was responding to "Then you can make as trivial edits as you desire" which isn't good advice.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer, but I've always found this to be a useless rule.  If there's one character wrong in a code sample, then just let the nicer passerby fix it without demanding that they also find five other characters of imperfect grammar to fix.

Comment: A one-character change in English text is likely (but not certain) to be trivial. A one-character change in code very likely is not.

Comment: Yes. They are still "discouraged", but they are not forbidden. That's the distinction here. As Keith points out, whether something is actually trivial is subjective. Once you get to 2k rep, you're trusted to make that judgment for yourself, rather than having a character count determine it for you. @agf