# Editing just one character when it matters

Tags: feature-request, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What about lowering the edit character limit for characters in code snippets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116436/what-about-lowering-the-edit-character-limit-for-characters-in-code-snippets)

I understand the restriction on question/answer edit to prevent useless, meaningless and treacherous changes to get votes.

[Here is an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721056/new-use-html5-semantic-markup-option-on-file-new-mvc-3-project/6431863#6431863) that needs edit, just one character and it won't be allowed. Hope the user that posted the answer can change it? Then one could suggest to the user the required changes.

[image]

The `<script` is open, needs a `>`.

Great job.

Comment: The line with the missing `>` is `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")"`. Do double quotes nest like that in HTML?

Comment: And I've added a link to this question to the answer. (I could edit the answer myself, but I'm not sure about the `"` characters).

Comment: I think that that would be considered too basic and a programmer asking a question concerning HTML can be considered knowing enough of it to to realize that tags need to be closed. Just like c++ programmers realize it's i++; as opposed to i+;

Comment: @KeithThompson: That's just a ASP templating call being inserted there.

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the missing angle bracket. In future, just leave a comment on the answer to notify the OP of the error.

Comment: You can just flag such post in the future, choose "other" and explain the edit that has to be made. Moderator can do it in a matter of seconds.

Comment: Hmmm, @Sha, I wouldn't be surprised if such flag would be dismissed... Tunmise, I know the editing features of Stack Exchange makes one eager to fix things. Just remember you cannot fix the whole world, and on many sites you cannot fix anything at all. I'd just leave a comment instead. (In fact, that HTML fragment might be an exact copy of what Visual Studio gives one...?)

Comment: @Arjan in case of glaring error that is obviously result of innocent typo it's "edit worthy" even if only one character - I think many people think this way including moderators. Posting here is one way but flag is faster and will cause less "noise". Of course there is a "risk" the moderator handling the flag won't agree but even so,  not a big deal.

Comment: @Arjan (+1) for _Stack Exchange makes one eager to fix things_. But I think we can remove the points on EDIT or only assign it if character more than 6 characters. So if anybody makes edit of less than 6 characters, no point. Then only those who really see a need to edit would. I think the "THANK YOU for your edit" message is enough as a reward - IMO

Comment: Most times I try not to edit unless the post is not easily readable which may discourage users from answering a question or an answer's content could confuse  a user. Like some users would copy a code into their browser and instead of looking at what was wrong, would comment "the code is not working"