# How to deal with code which is wrong due to the case sensitive nature of the language?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow, edits, character-limit

On Stack Overflow I find many code snippets which are otherwise correct but will throw an error because of the case sensitive nature of the programming language it's written in (Java, Unix, etc).

I try to edit them when possible. But am asking the question because most of the time the changes are less than 6 characters and so editing is not possible. I leave comments but most are ignored.

Is it necessary for a minimum characters cap for editing? I have seen 'Title' can be edited with just one change. And reviewers can easily reject edits which are not useful.

Or will it be useful if we remove the minimum character cap for editing when it is in a code block?

Stack Overflow code snippets have helped millions (including me numerous times) and it hurts to see such trivial mistakes in them.

Comment: If you have 2k+ rep, then you can make all of the trivial edits you want.

Comment: Ah!!! Thanks..didn't know that. That answers my query(about minimum character cap).

Another doubt...is your comment not worthy of being an answer??

Comment: duplicate of [What about lowering the edit character limit for characters in code snippets?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116436/165773)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would argue that this is very rarely a situation that poses itself, and it helps to keep the review queue clean. Since once you have > 2k rep this isn't a factor anyway, the best option in this scenario is to flag the answer for attention by a moderator. Not only does it help you towards your 'Marshal' badge, it helps to ensure that other edits aren't missed as well (e.g. spelling & grammatical errors).

Comment: Oh! So we can flag mods for such issues too. Hmmm!! Ok!!

Answer (score 9):

### Please **do not** edit case-sensitive code!

This can make answering a question impossible if the code is *seemingly* completely correct after editing.

When this situation arises, I would either answer a question with the corrected case of the code (with any other changes necessary, of course), or post a comment on an answer that has improper casing.

Comment: This depends on whether the code is in a question, and whether it is the main point of the question. You should correct it if it is un-related to the main point of question, or if the code is in an answer.

Comment: @ronalchn: I was bothered about the code in the answers.