# Minimum 6 character edit is not a practical rule

Tags: discussion, edits

I just wanted to express my concern over the 6 character edit rule.

Many times I came over answers posted by users which have some error in codes they posted. And usually the errors in their posts are syntax error. And of course even 1 incorrect character causes an error.

These errors can create a lot of confusions sometimes. What am I supposed to do to correct the syntax errors if there is a minimum 6 character rule?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17981507/android-listview-item-style/17981783#17981783), an example in the accepted answer, there is an syntax error in the XML code.

Comment: you shouldn't edit code in questions

Comment: Leave a comment describing the error, so people viewing the answer will see your comment.

Comment: Also: [What about lowering the edit character limit for characters in code snippets?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116436)

Comment: @Amaterasu As i stated in my post, its the **answers** that I'm talking about, not the question its self...

Comment: no worries, then do what AlienArrays suggests

Comment: My point is: It's been discussed _ad nauseum_. It's not going to be changed.

Comment: @AlienArrays its not always feasible to explain the error in the comment section, sometimes there are multiple errors so it difficult to point out the error since its not practical to always mention the line number in large pieces of code

Comment: @vidhu fix grammar and spelling errors. Improve the answer overall and not just syntax error if it's not enough

Comment: Earn some more reputation and the limit goes away.

Comment: @vidhu - If there are *multiple errors* then probably 6 characters limit won't disturb you while suggesting edits.

Answer (score 3):

Edits are supposed to improved overall the questions or the answers. It's usually possible to do more than just simple edits like "fixing syntax errors". Keep in mind that small edits might even get rejected in the review queue when they are too small.

I die a little every time I see small edits that are fixing a word and retype it incorretly.

Usually if I see such errors like a missing semicolon or something close to it. It isn't hard to edit more than code snippets. Often people makes typos and it is possible to fix grammar errors or rephrase things that aren't clear. As long as the edit are improving the question without "changing" its meaning. You'll never have problem with the 6 char minimum.

Also, code snippet that are changed in a way that drastically change the algorithm might get rejected too.

I'll add that code edits should not be made in questions and possibly only in answers. As trivial as it might seem, code formatting for a python program could be actually fixing a syntax error. For that reason, people are probably more expecting to see the code in question "as-is" than fixed. If you want to fix the code in a question, post an answer instead.

The 6 char limit isn't a bad thing in my opinion. It's like the 15 char minimum in comments. It will prevent abuse and really small edits that don't really improve much the question/answer.

Comment: Code edits can also "fix" the problem, which is what we _don't_ want.

Comment: Except for answers which should not contain errors in the first place.

Comment: not sure if you're making a joke, but if you weren't, I was referring to questions