# Why can't a suggested edit be just one character? Typos usually are one character

Tags: discussion, support, review, edits, suggested-edits

Quoting the accepted answer from
[What about lowering the edit character limit for characters in code snippets?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116436/what-about-lowering-the-edit-character-limit-for-characters-in-code-snippets):

> There may be an exception where all that is needed is a one letter fix. However it is a huge exception, not a rule.

Isn't this an exception? Within code snippet `sib` and `sob` means two different things (input / output).

Why can't an edit be just one character? Typos usually are one character...

For example in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148688/network-statistics-on-linux/148708#148708), `sib` should be `sob` in line #6

Saying that I should make more changes as to have more than 6 characters doesn't make sense as this is the one (rather important) change I want to make. Also, I'm aware that you need 2K points to edit freely - but I can't see how to suggest an edit without flagging it for a moderator.. am I missing something?

Comment: Just comment under the post and presumably OP will fix it. Sometimes the error *is* the answer too.

Comment: Only users who are limited to making **suggested edits** are restricted in this way. A user with sufficient reputation to edit can change this. Work on getting your reputation up and you'll be able to do this, too.

Comment: The dupe, obviously, since it is written from an SO perspective, *also* considers the occasional possibility of a one-character edit being important in order to fix computer input. So there's no sense in which this question describes a situation that is not comprehended in the given dupe.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek point taken. Downvoting twice for a question that admittedly is a duplicate is quite the way to welcome new-comers tho imo. lighten up people

Comment: Meta's strange like that. I only/merely closevoted though.

Comment: @Elad nothing personal here, no welcome here, either good or bad. You imply that you want users with low rep to be able to make such edits, those who downvoted don't want such a feature. That's all.

Comment: Why do I need reputation to change "lead" to "led", when I don't need reputation to change "lead" to "led (originally misspelt as 'lead')"? This kind of paternalism in SE drives me completely nuts.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it *is* an exception, but one that's so exceedingly rare that making the edit system even more complicated isn't quite justified (at least, not yet).

I completely see what you're saying and very much agree that it's almost absurdly exacerbated by the example you gave - but it (and by 'it' I mean):

- Simple typo that could mean the difference between input and output, for instance
- ***absolutely nothing else that can be improved, expanded upon, formatted properly, etc***

... doesn't happen often enough to really justify the additional complexity. I'm not opposed to revisiting some way to make these cases not break *if they become a rampant problem*, but only a very small fraction of edits hit this. Interestingly, when we looked into establishing 'honeypots' to train the spam systems on spam edits, many edits abandoned by bots were stopped by this (though the potential for abuse isn't an ideal case to base fundamental decisions upon, I'm just mentioning it).

I'm not saying it's perfect as-is, but the noise that these could generate for the suggested edit queue alone would make things *much* less ideal for folks than knowing that we reject a handful of decent yet tiny edits every day.

The frustration you must have felt here is really unfortunate and I'm not disagreeing with you at all on the premise; I'm just saying the fix here is going to be quite a bit worse than the problem it fixes.

Comment: Eliminating the 6-character quota would be a *reduction* in complexity, not an increase.  And how would you know how commonly something occurs if it's not currently possible to occur at all? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/472/revisions