# Why should an edit be of at least 6 characters?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

I'm doing my first reviews on Stack Overflow, and sometimes just formatting need to be corrected.

I formatted a code snippet but the system does not allow me to save the changes because
the edit needs to be of at least 6 characters.

So what should I do? Replace some words with synonyms to step over the 6 character limitation?

Comment: @nhahtdh  But if it vitally needs reformatting? For example, all text is within paragraph mixed with large code snippets.

Comment: Because reviewing suggested edits takes time on the part of several other users, and devoting manpower to really minor edits would be a waste of their time. If there is a glaring problem that can only be addressed with a <6 character edit, a user with editing privileges will probably fix it. You can leave a comment to help speed up the process.

Comment: @zavg: Since it is in review queue, leave it to other higher rep user (2k+) who can do edit without limit.

Comment: @nhahtdh Ok, I understand now

Comment: Write an algorithm that allows a misspelled word to be replaced by a correctly spelled word, under the six character limit, and doesn't require human eyes to review it.

Comment: Alternatively, it is a duplicate of [Change this behavior to allow for spelling corrections and the like: “Edits must be at least 6 characters”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82534).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of adding blank spaces so that the formatting is better; you should post a comment asking the OP to do so themselves.

*This may sometimes be skipped if the posts are quite old.* In which case; you can always search for smaller edits/title updates/retagging.

If you're still unsure about it; leave the post as it is!

Comment: what if answer is pretty excelent but there is `"` instead of `'` so the code doesn't work. that's 1 character change but completely reasonable..