# Unable to get value from answer due to restricted edit

Tags: support, edits, markdown

I was just recently searching here and on other Metas about certain markdown options when writing posts, for example:

<s>scratching</s>

> spoilers

<sub>subscripts and others...</sub>

Eventually I found the post [Different types of quotes in answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345673/3908170), which explained the markdown I was looking for (subscripts). I proceeded to **simulate an `edit` on the answer**, so I could *see how it was formatted on raw text*, but came with a warning saying:

[image]

Is this because I have still not reached the 2k edit milestone, and all my edits are still suggested edits on SO?

I have seen other questions where you have to simulate and edit on the answer to see what the answerer (and the question) is actually about (and actually tried it), so one can learn by example how to get that formatting. For example, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82535/332286) great answer. It seems that this can only be done in Meta SE.

I eventually found another post that helped me, and that didn't require to simulate an edit to learn about it, but took me even more time and searching to reach it. **What alternatives one has to get the value of answers in similar situations?**

Comment: The editor has a help section. There's a complete markdown help page as well (also linked from the editor help - the ? mark) - https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help

Comment: Good suggestions as alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can visit the Revision History of the answer:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/82535/revisions

(usually reachable via the 'edited <date>' link underneath the post, but if not, you can construct it from the post ID). The Revision History contains 'source' links

[image]

which will lead you to the raw Markdown source of the post:

[image]

---

Alternatively, use a SEDE query like [this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/731788/markdown-source-for-last-revision?PostId=82535) to get the Markdown source of the latest revision of a post, specified by its ID.

Comment: Yep, worked also for the [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/eceb5a79-17d2-4ea0-aecb-04f8293d23c9/view-source) I mentioned. Thanks for the help.