# Should we edit spelling mistakes or not?

Tags: discussion, edits, help-text

You can't ask for

- to fix grammatical or spelling mistakes

and discourage

- tiny, trivial and single character edits

at the same time.

...to distinguish this from other questions: I don’t care if fixing spelling is encouraged or not. But please fix the help-text to not ask for both. On top: I'm in favor of trivial edits. Who is hurt by one-char-corrections?

Comment: I interpret that to mean when the only thing wrong with the question is that the letter i is not capitalized, for instance.

Comment: Your comment is as ambiguous as the help-text (your example is one for “fix grammatical mistakes” (edit them) or one for “trivial” (don’t edit them)???)

Comment: Their r posts wth a ridikulous # of tipos, and then there are posts with a single miner typo; posts with grammatical/spelling mistakes don't always result in trivial edits -- in fact, they almost never do

Comment: @Robert: No its not, you are just confused :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81520/how-to-overcome-edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters), [Minor edit of posts: allow typo correction for low-rep users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80851/minor-edit-of-posts-allow-typo-correction-for-low-rep-users), [Remove “corrected spelling” from the Edit Summary suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80635/remove-corrected-spelling-from-the-edit-summary-suggestion)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The full sentence reported in the privilege page is the following one:

> Try to make the post substantively better when you edit, not just change a single character. Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged.

The sentence doesn't say that tiny, trivial edits are forbidden.

The sense of what the privilege page is trying to communicate is that, when you find a word that is misspelled (for example), you should also check if there is something else in the post that needs to be changed to make it better; if there is something else that needs to be changed, then you should change that as well, to avoid the need for somebody else to edit the post once again.
If you find the following text in a question, you should not just change the function name, but also change the punctuation used in the sentence.

> i want, to use the Drupal function `load_user()`. but it's does not return an object i, can use. any help, plaese?

That doesn't mean single character edits are forbidden; there are surely some cases where a misspelled word needs a single character edit, and where the word as it is written would cause the post to be misunderstood.

The only users who cannot make any single character edits are the users without the privilege of editing posts. The text reported in the privilege page is still valid for those users; the only difference is that for such users the suggestion to avoid single characters edit is forced.
The reason for having that reinforcement is that the edits made from the users who don't have the privilege to edit posts are suggestions that somebody else needs to review; rather than requiring users to review a proposed edit that should be rejected because is changing a single character, it is better to have an automatic checking that avoids those edits, and require a user's review for something less trivial. I can imagine that avoiding users get reputation for trivial editing a post is another reason to avoid single character edits from who doesn't have the privilege of editing any posts. (Between the two reasons, the latter is probably the less important one.)

Comment: but those who doesn't have access to editing, they're getting: Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this

Comment: For who doesn't have the privilege of editing posts, I can see two reasons to block single character edits: To avoid they get reputation for such easy edits is the first one. The other reason is that those edits are going to be reviewed before to be accepted; rather than requiring a user to review a proposed edit that should be rejected because is changing a single character, it is better to have an automatic checking that avoids those edits, and require a user's review for something less trivial.

Comment: How has the power to edit the help-text? Is it useful to discuss this here? I think the text should be changed... – If the system does not allow tiny edits under some conditions, the text should say so, because otherwise a little correction should be preferred over no correction and not “discouraged”.

Comment: @Robert Siemer The only users who cannot make a single character edit are who don't have the privilege of editing posts. A privilege page describes a specific privilege, and it's clearly meant for who has that privilege. If I read the [Protected questions](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/protect-questions) page, I cannot assume that what reported there is valid also for who doesn't have that privilege, except where clearly stated.

Comment: Sorry, I was lured into thinking, people with edit rights have to go through peer review as well. – Okay, so for people _with_ edit rights: they get reputation for editing?? How much? When? This should be mentioned on the help-text then! And I personally agree giving reputation for single-char-edits as well. It takes as much effort to correct a single spelling mistake as does the correction of six. – Trivial changes should not be discouraged at all, if it is only because of (undocumented) reputation points. These edits could also be automatically non-rewarding instead of automatically rejected

Comment: @Robert Siemer Users with the privilege of editing every post don't get any reputation from editing posts. IMO, you should not get any reputation gain for editing a misspelled word out of six misspelled words. If you are taking your time to edit the post, then you should edit all the misspelled words. Also, allowing single character edits would mean allowing a user to get a reputation increase of twelve points instead of two, just for the fact the user edits the six misspelled words one at time.